# SQL Performance with stacking

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to understand will there be a performance impact if I stack `Table1` as in `Table2`? Which is better for performance?

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ID = 100
```

Output:

```
ID  col1 col2
-------------
100  1    0
200  0    1
300  1    0
400  0    1
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE ID = 100
```

Output:

```
ID   col    data
----------------
100  col1    1
100  col2    0
200  col1    0
200  col2    1
300  col1    1
300  col2    0
400  col1    0
400  col2    1
```

Also how does SQL Server scan the records?

Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is call [**UNPIVOT**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396). Each one has use. Table2 will be bigger, but with proper index will have similar performance.

Comment: If you just have fixed 2 conditions (data of 1 or 2), you don't need to do UNPIVIOT because you can just self join on ID and data.

Comment: That's a bit strange that any other part of your system does not care whether there'll be several rows or several cols in resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table 1 is normalized, while table 2 is designed as [**EAV**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) which is considered as an anti-pattern, and with good reasons.

And While I believe that performance would be better with Table 1,
There are some other factors to be considered here besides performance.

IMHO, the only good reason to choose an EAV design is when you don't have any other choice. (and that's rarely the case, since most databases today can handle complicated data types such as XML or JSON)  In this case, the choice is quite obvious - Table 1 has a better design, no question about it.